# Trying to demarshal JSON response using Java Classes

Tags: java, json, marshalling, unmarshalling

I am trying to demarshal JSON response using Java Classes, I am new to Java so it may be a school boy error I am making.

The JSON response is:

```
[{
    "index": 514042,
    "source_list_name": "insurance_group",
    "allow_multiple_account_associates": false,
    "source_list_index": 10078,
    "fields": {
        "type": "e212"
    },
    "is_editable": false,
    "allow_associates": false
}, {
    "is_editable": true,
    "fields": {
        "type": "i120"
    },
    "allow_associates": false,
    "allow_multiple_account_associates": false,
    "index": 533402
}, {
    "is_editable": true,
    "fields": {
        "type": "i119"
    },
    "allow_associates": false,
    "allow_multiple_account_associates": false,
    "index": 514519
}]
```

The Java Class is:

```
package com.ls.json.pack

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class EmploymentSalaryTypeResponse {

    public class Fields{
        private String type;
    }

    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Data
    public class Root{
        private int index;
        private String source_list_name;
        private boolean allow_multiple_account_associates;
        private int source_list_index;
        private Fields fields;
        private boolean is_editable;
        private boolean allow_associates;
    }
}
```

The error I get is:

Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `com.ls.json.pack.EmploymentSalaryTypeResponse` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)
at [Source: (org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBufferInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1746)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1520)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1467)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeFromArray(BeanDeserializer.java:650)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:211)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:187)

Can you see where I am going wrong please?

I tried to re-vamp the class but no joy

Comment: What you are trying to unmarshal is a JSON array. You need to adapt your parsing code to allow that, currently you apparently try to make a single `EmploymentSalaryTypeResponse` out of it which won't work. Can you try changing the type of your controller parameter (assuming that's where you use it) to `EmploymentSalaryTypeResponse[]`?

Comment: @experimentunit1998X why? doesn't the current code of `EmploymentSalaryTypeResponse` match the json?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, consider making the inner classes static. Additionally, add `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)`.

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class EmploymentSalaryTypeResponse {

    @Data
    public static class Fields{
        private String type;
    }

    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public static class Root{
        private int index;
        private String source_list_name;
        private boolean allow_multiple_account_associates;
        private int source_list_index;
        private Fields fields;
        private boolean is_editable;
        private boolean allow_associates;
    }
}
```

After that, as you see, you are trying to parse a List object, so try to use the appropriate data type when parsing. If you want to manually do the parsing, you can use a `TypeReference`:

```
var mapper = new ObjectMapper();
var type = new TypeReference<List<EmploymentSalaryTypeResponse.Root>>(){};
var object = mapper.readValue(json, type);
System.out.println(object);
```

On the other hand, this is  automatically deserialized by Spring, you can change the method signature to accept a `List<EmploymentSalaryTypeResponse.Root>` and it should work.